# The good old IE problem

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I have the following code:

http://jsbin.com/egiju4

That works a treat on FF and chrome, but shows all the blocks aligned in IE.

I've made loads of changes to it, but can't get it to work at all.

Would anyone please be able to give me some help with it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should post what you are going for.  I look and see a table in Chrome/FF and have no idea why you don't just use a table element here.  Why make it complicated?  You clearly *need* a table.

Comment: @Brad not necessarily, depends entirely on what the table-looking structure really is.

Comment: @Brad He doesn't, of course. This layout can be achieved using UL and LI elements as the OP demonstrated. Tables are for tabular data (and we don't what for the OP is using this).

Comment: Yep, tables is not an option here, and as @Šime Vidas stated, tables should be used for tabular data, and this is  a selector. my example does not demonstrate the whole of it though

Comment: Ah, given the incomplete nature of what you were doing, I assumed you had tabular data.  If not, then no, don't use tables.

Comment: @Brad I don't see how you mean it's incomplete. Maybe you didn't read it properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set overflow:auto on the UL elements:

```
 .selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; overflow:auto; }
```

***Update:***

I am not sure which versions of IE have problems if you don't additionally define a width on the UL elements, but just to be safe, you can always set width:100%:

```
 .selectable { list-style-type:none; margin:0; padding:0;
               overflow:auto; width:100%; }
```

Comment: That seemed to work as well as adding a width. However, I reckon is a bit more elegant, as it doesn't require me to hard-code the width. Would you mind telling me why this fixes the problem?

Comment: @Marcos When you have an element that contains child elements that are floated, then you need to set overflow:auto on the parent in order to ensure that the parent encapsulates its child elements. This technique is well known for years: http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2005/03/clearing_floats.html

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure I have used this before, but this always ends up biting me back from time to time. Thanks a lot though

Answer (score 3):

Add `width` css rule to encapsulating div.

```
  #block_selector {
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
    width:400px; /*this*/
  }
```

Comment: @Raveren No need for having to define a width. overflow:auto will do just fine.

Comment: @Šime I thought you need to define a width (in other words, _give it layout_) for the benefit of IE, otherwise `overflow:auto` will not have the desired effect? Or am I still thinking in terms of IE6?

Comment: @w3d Are you saying that the overflow:auto technique does not work in IE6 unless you also define a width? I don't have IE6 on my machine, so that I cannot test this.

Comment: @Šime Yes, a width (or a height) is needed in IE6. To [quote PPK from your link above](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/clearing.html#link5), "The use of a width or height declaration is required to make the effect work in Explorer Windows and Opera. If you don't include it Explorer Windows continues to show the border at the top of the columns, as if there were no overflow. Opera completely hides the content of the container.". However, your answer above clearly works OK in IE8 (and Opera 10.63) so this appears to be _fixed_ in current browsers (thanks for the insight). What about IE7?

Comment: @w3d Well, the article was written 5 years ago, so the "Opera in question" was probably Opera 7.5 :) I am pretty sure that Opera "fixed" this issue long ago. I don't know about IE7, but since IE6 has a larger market share anyway, `width:100%` is required.

Answer (score 2):

Add `clear:left` or `clear:both` to your "selectable" class to clear the floats on the list items.

Answer (score 1):

Add `clear: left;` rule to `.selectable`:

```
.selectable { list-style-type: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; clear:left; }
```

This will ensure each `<ul>` clears any floated elements before it.